# VB.Net SQLite Select Statement with Single Quote Error

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, select, escaping

I have an SQLite table with a column that contains entries that have already had any single-quote characters doubled to escape them. An example is:

```
MD Prince George''s
```

I want to query this table to see if I can find the above entry. This code shows a small test program to attempt to do this:

```vb
Private Sub TEST2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TEST2.Click
    Dim sql() As String = {"LIKE 'MD Prince George%';",
                           "= 'MD Prince George''s';",
                           "= 'MD Prince George's';"}
    Dim ThisTable As New List(Of DataRow)

    For a As Integer = 0 To sql.Count - 1
        Try
            Connect(2)  ' Getting my connection
            Using tr As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction
                Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `counties` WHERE `STATE_COUNTY` " & sql(a)
                    Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As New DataTable
                        da.Fill(dt)

                        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                            ThisTable.Add(dt.Rows(0))
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Using
                tr.Commit()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try

        Debug.WriteLine("Result(" & a & ": " & sql(a) & ") gives ThisTable.Count=" & ThisTable.Count)
    Next
End Sub
```

The results are:

```
Result(0: LIKE 'MD Prince George%';) gives ThisTable.Count=1
Result(1: = 'MD Prince George''s';) gives ThisTable.Count=1
SQLite error (1): near "s": syntax error
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll
SQL logic error
near "s": syntax error
Result(2: = 'MD Prince George's';) gives ThisTable.Count=1
```

This shows that the first statement was matched: I include it to prove there is such an entry in the table. The second statement, trying to match 2 single quotes with 2 single quotes, returns no result. The third statement, trying to match 2 single quotes with 1 single quote, returns an error.

My question: what should my select statement be to find the entirety of that single entry, or other entries which might have 2 single quotes in them? No, I don't want to only find %''%.

Comment: The second statement works?! `Result(1: = 'MD Prince George''s';) gives ThisTable.Count=1` - doubling single quotes is a usual approach in some SQL dialects, and SQLite certainly is such a dialect. Also, consider using SQL placeholders instead.

Comment: @Corion: The list isn’t cleared, so if it found anything, it should give `ThisTable.Count=2`.

Comment: TimMakins: Are you looking for `= 'MD Prince George''''s'`? `''''` in a single-quoted string literal represents two single quotes of text.

Comment: No, the second statement does not work. If it had, the 'ThisTable.Count' would have increased to 2, because each iteration is adding a new row with 'ThisTable.Add(dt.Rows(0))'. Yes, I have looked at placeholders but can not figure out the code that would work in this exact instance.

Comment: @Ry: Yes, that is the correct answer: = 'MD Prince George''''s'; I hadn't realised that I had to do that - thank you. If anyone could also show how to do it with placeholders, I am sure it would be interesting to many.

Comment: I am wondering why, when you have a lovely DataTable with DataRows, you would want extra code to add the DataRow to a list. You can access your data just as easily from a DataTable as from a List(Of DataRow).

Comment: I am wondering why you would put escaped data in your database.

Comment: @itsLex - because it was the only way it would work with a command like:
    data = "MD Prince George's"
    sql = "INSERT INTO `counties` (STATE_COUNTY) VALUES ('" & data & "');"

but it you can correct me, that would be great.